# Java Awt components are displayed but Swing components are not displayed in Applet

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt

I am trying to run a very simple Java applet program.
When I  used `AWT.Label` component, I can see the component through appletviewer.  The code I am using is:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class AppletTest extends Applet
{

  Label user = new Label("Username", Label.LEFT);

    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
     g.drawString("Registration Form", 195, 10);
    }

     public void init()
     {
       add(user);
     }

 }
```

When I use `swing.JLabel` component, I cannot see any component on the screen except for Registration form printed on top:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class AppletTest extends JApplet
{

  JLabel user = new JLabel("Username", JLabel.LEFT);

    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
     g.drawString("Registration Form", 195, 10);
    }

     public void init()
     {
       add(user);
     }

 }
```

What is the issue?

Comment: thanks Nick Rippe :) for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `paint` is a method in `JApplet`, when you override it, you need to call `super.paint(g)` so that the parent component can still do it's painting.  Your `paint` method should look something more like this:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawString("Registration Form", 195, 10);
}
```

Comment: thnak you Nick Rippe:) that worked. But I encountered an other problem.If I add too many JLabels just one after the other,Only the last one is shown

Comment: You probably want a container to hold all of your Labels - then add the container to your applet.  I would suggest using `Box`.  You can easily create one using `Box.createVerticalBox();`

Comment: Also, don't forget an up-vote = thank you.  :)  Accepted answer = Yay! It works!